# HTTP Longpolling with changing request parameters using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, long-polling

I need to implement HTTP Longpolling using rxjs (in an Angular environment). The challenge is that I need to change the request parameters on every call. To be more specific: I need to change the from/to values to have it rolling. For example always go back 1 minute in time from the current time.

Right now I have the following implementation:

```
const requestParameter$ = new BehaviorSubject<MetricAggregationParams>(initialRequestParameter);

this.metricsService
  .searchAggregatedMetrics(requestParameter$)
  .pipe(
    tap((metricInstancesResult) => {
      // do something with the result
    }),
    delay(3000),
    tap(() => {
      requestParameter$.next({
        ...requestParameter$.value,
        from: DateTime.now()
          .minus({ minutes: timerange.timerangeInMinutes as number })
          .toISO(),
        to: DateTime.now().toISO()
      });
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
})

searchAggregatedMetrics(requestParameter$: BehaviorSubject<MetricAggregationParamsDto>) {
  return requestParameter$.pipe(
    concatMap((requestParameter) =>
      this.http.post<MetricAggregationResult>(`REST_URL`, requestParameter)
    )
  );
}
```

Here are some constraints:

- The first request should start right away (no delay)
- The next request should start after the previous request has finished + 3000ms

Is there a way to have the longpolling logic all together in the searchAggregatedMetrics method?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, you are facing some kind of recursive problem. Recursion in rxJs is addressed with the `expand` operator.

One solution to your problem could be along these lines

```
restService(0).pipe(
  delay(300),
  map(resp => {
    console.log("do stuff with resp " + resp)
  }),
  map(() => {
    console.log("prepare next input " + counter++)
    return counter
  }),
  // expand is an operator that takes as input a function that
  // returns an Observable
  expand(input => {
    return restService(counter).pipe(
      delay(300),
      map(resp => {
        console.log("do stuff with resp " + resp)
      }),
      map(() => {
        console.log("prepare next input " + counter++)
        return counter
      }),
    )
  }),
  // we use take just to finish the iteration after a certain number of calls
  take(10)
).subscribe()

// counter used to simulate the fact that we change input at every call
let counter = 0
// function to simulate a rest service call
function restService(input: number) {
  return of(input).pipe(
    tap(input => console.log("Input received " + input)),
    map(input => {
      const resp = "response " + input
      return resp
    })
  )
}
```

There is clearly a repetition in the above code, which can therefore coded a bit more elegantly (but maybe less clearly) like this

```
function restServiceOnSteroids(input: number) {
  return restService(input).pipe(
    delay(300),
    map(resp => {
      console.log("do stuff with resp " + resp)
    }),
    map(() => {
      console.log("prepare next input " + counter++)
      return counter
    })
  )
}

restServiceOnSteroids(counter).pipe(
  expand(input => restServiceOnSteroids(input)),
  take(7)
).subscribe()
```

Here a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dgwqn1?file=index.ts) that reproduces this solution